# HTML/CSS hide background image for printing with CSS media query

Tags: css, html, media-queries

I'm learning HTML / CSS and wanted to know, how to hide the body background image for printing process with the use of media query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And just in case you're not sure what the style should be, based on the information you've given, it would be:

```
@media print {
    body{
        background-image: none;
    }
}
```

Best of luck with the rest of your learning!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic media query, wrap your style inside this media query:

```
@media print {
    // Your style here
}
```